# Values for multiple locations and years in Google Earth Engine

Tags: google-earth-engine, google-earth-engine-javascript-api

I am using the TerraClim data in Earth Engine to obtain location and year specific temperature values. I have 12 districts and TerraClim has data from 1958 to 2015. **For each district, I want to get the mean of max temperature (during January - April) for each year.** I was able to get the mean max temperature (Jan-Apr) for each year. But, for some reason, the *reduceRegion() or reduceRegions()* is not working. Need help to ultimately create a table with: District attribute, mean temperature for each year between 1958 and 2015.

```
//Image and shapefile import
var images = ee.ImageCollection("IDAHO_EPSCOR/TERRACLIMATE"),
var districts = ee.FeatureCollection("users/asifishti/IGP_dist");

//Selecting maximum temperature band 
var image_maxtmp = images.select ("tmmx");
print (image_maxtmp);

//Filtering image for Jan - April and 1958 and 2015
var maxtmp_janapr = image_maxtmp.filter(ee.Filter.calendarRange(1958,2015,'year'))
.filter(ee.Filter.calendarRange(1,4,'month'))
print (maxtmp_janapr);

//Getting yearwise max temperature image
var year = ee.List.sequence (1958,2015);
var mean_func = function (i) {
  return maxtmp_janapr.mean().set("Year", i)
};

var yearwise_maxtmp = ee.ImageCollection(year.map(mean_func));
print (yearwise_maxtmp);

//Calculating max temp for each district (NOT WORKING)
var dist_maxtmp = function(feature){
  var mean_maxtmp = yearwise_maxtmp.reduceRegions({
    reducer: ee.Reducer.mean(),
    geometry: feature.geometry(),
    scale: 4000, //The image has 2.5 arc-second/~4km resolution
    maxPixels: 1e12
  });
  var maxtmp_dist = feature.set("Max Temp", mean_maxtmp.get("tmmx"));
  return maxtmp_dist;
};

var distwise = districts.map(dist_maxtmp);
print (distwise);
```

Comment: Additional information: The districts are non-contiguous.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem with your code is that you are calling `reduceRegions()` on `yearwise_maxtmp`, which is an `ee.ImageCollection`. It can only be called on an `ee.Image`. Here's one way to do this:

```
// var districts = ee.FeatureCollection("users/asifishti/IGP_dist")
// You didn't share your districts
var districts = ee.FeatureCollection([
  ee.Feature(ee.Geometry.Point([0, 10]).buffer(10000), {'District': 'District A'}),
  ee.Feature(ee.Geometry.Point([50, 10]).buffer(10000), {'District': 'District B'})
])

var startYear = 1958
var endYear = 2015
var startMonth = 1
var endMonth = 4

var yearlyMeans = ee.FeatureCollection(
  ee.List.sequence(startYear, endYear)
    .map(calculateYearlyMeans)
).flatten()

print(yearlyMeans)  
print(
  ui.Chart.feature.groups({
    features: yearlyMeans, 
    xProperty: 'Year', 
    yProperty: 'Max Temp', 
    seriesProperty: 'District'
  })
)

Export.table.toDrive({
  collection: yearlyMeans, 
  description: 'yearlyMeans',
  selectors: ['District', 'Year', 'Max Temp']
})


function calculateYearlyMeans(year) {
  year = ee.Number(year)
  var mean = ee.ImageCollection('IDAHO_EPSCOR/TERRACLIMATE')
    .select("tmmx")
    .filter(ee.Filter.calendarRange(year, year.add(1), 'year'))
    .filter(ee.Filter.calendarRange(startMonth, endMonth, 'month'))      
    .mean()
  return districts.map(function (district) {
    return calculateDistrictMean(district, year, mean)
  })
}

function calculateDistrictMean(district, year, mean) {
  var districtMean = mean.reduceRegion({
    reducer: ee.Reducer.mean(),
    geometry: district.geometry(),
    scale: 4000,
    maxPixels: 1e12
  })
  return district
    .set('Max Temp', districtMean.get('tmmx'))  
    .set('Year', year)
}
```

https://code.earthengine.google.com/bfccec9c678a65aa3de98b26d36abe4c

Comment: Thank you so much, Daniel! This is really a nice solution.